# how to rectify the error "PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object"?

Tags: php, pdo

guys i'm trying to get a login script to work in openshift. nd i get the error

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

i was struggling to make it work from yesterday still no luck with it. i would be happy if i get any solutions here.

here is the method from the class that is trying to login to the page.

```
public function viewProtectedArea($unamel,$passl) 
                {
               try{
                   $active=1;
                   $stmth= $this->_db->prepare("select * from user where uname=:uname and pass=:pass and activated=:one");
                   $stmth->bindValue(":uname",$unamel);
                 $stmth->bindValue(":pass",$passl);
                  $stmth->bindValue(":one",$active);
                   $stmth->execute();
                  return $stmth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
               } catch (PDOException $e){
                   echo $e->getMessage();
               }

           }
```

and here is the login backend script:

```
<?php   

include_once 'dbconfig.inc.php';
if (isset($_POST['submit-login'])) {
$uname= htmlspecialchars($_POST['unamel']);
$unamel=  stripslashes($_POST['unamel']);
$pass= htmlspecialchars($_POST['passl']);
$pass1= stripslashes($_POST['passl']);
$passl=  md5($pass1);
$user = $project->viewProtectedArea($unamel,$passl);
    if ($user!="") {

                 $_SESSION['id']=$user['user_id'];
                  $_SESSION['fname']=$user['fname'];
                   $_SESSION['lname']=$user['lname'];
                  $_SESSION['uname']=$user['uname'];
                  $_SESSION['email']=$user['email'];
                  $_SESSION['phone']=$user['phone'];
                  $_SESSION['avatar']=$user['avatar'];
                  $_SESSION['app']=TRUE;
                  $user_ok=TRUE;
                   header("location: ../home.php?u={$_SESSION['uname']}"); 


    }  else {
        header("location: ../index.php?nosession");
    }





}
```

"plus dont mind the md5 i'm just experimenting"

Comment: You don't need to use htmlspecialchars as prepared statements do all the work for you.  Try specifying the data type when binding (example: $stmh->bindValue(":pass",$pass,PDO::PARAM_INT) and so on).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an exception because there is no instance of $this->_db (therefor is null).

Doing a `var_dump($this->_db)` may tell you if that is the case.